# Bad Resolution Image taken with getuserMedia() Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, camera, getusermedia

i wanted to take screenshots from a mobilephone camera using javascript getUserMedia function but resolution is very bad.

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
  // access the web cam
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   video: {
    width: { 
     min: 1280,
    },
    height: {
     min: 720,
    },
    facingMode: {
     exact: 'environment'
    }
   }
  }).then(function(stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.addEventListener('click', takeSnapshot);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      document.body.textContent = 'Could not access the camera. Error: ' + error.name;
  });
}


var video = document.querySelector('video'), canvas;

function takeSnapshot(){
  var img =  document.createElement('img');
  var context;
  var width = video.offsetWidth, height = video.offsetHeight;
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height; 
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');          
    context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.drawImage(video, 0,  0, width,  height);    
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
}
```

No errors-code, but resolution not good, i cannot read the text of the photo.
There is a method to get real image quality from camera?

Comment: Check [Get maximum video resolution with getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444179/387194)

Comment: Is the resolution not `1280`x`720`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**MediaCapture**

This is what you are using via getUserMedia.

If you have a camera which allows a 1920x1080, 1280x720, and 640x480 resolutions only, the browser implementation of Media Capture can emulate a 480x640 feed from the 1280x720 (see [MediaStream](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#mediastream)). From testing (primarily Chrome) the browser typically scales 720 down to 640 and then crops the center. Sometimes when I have used virtual camera software I see Chrome has added artificial black padding around a non supported resolution. The client sees a success message and a feed of the right dimensions but a person would see a qualitative degradation. Because of this emulation you cannot guarantee the feed is correct or not scaled. However it will typically have the correct dimensions requested.

You can read about constraints [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#constrainable-interface). It basically boils down to: Give me a resolution as close to x. Then the browser determines by its own implementation to reject the constraints and throw an error, get the resolution, or emulate the resolution.

More information of this design is detailed in the mediacapture specification. Especially:

> The RTCPeerConnection is an interesting object because it acts
>   simultaneously as both a sink and a source for over-the-network
>   streams. As a sink, it has source transformational capabilities (e.g.,
>   lowering bit-rates, scaling-up / down resolutions, and adjusting
>   frame-rates), and as a source it could have its own settings changed
>   by a track source.

The main reason for this is allowing n clients to have access to the same media source but may require different resolutions, bit rate, etc, thus emulation/scaling/transforming attempts to solve this problem. A negative to this is that you never truly know what the source resolution is.

**ImageCapture**

This is potentially your solution.

If 60FPS video isn't a hard requirement and you have leway on compatibility you can poll [ImageCapture](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/) to emulate a camera and receive a much clearer image from the camera.

You would have to check for clientside support and then potentially fallback on MediaCapture.

The API enables control over camera features such as zoom, brightness, contrast, ISO and white balance. Best of all, Image Capture allows you to access the full resolution capabilities of any available device camera or webcam. Previous techniques for taking photos on the Web have used video snapshots (MediaCapture rendered to a Canvas), which are lower resolution than that available for still images.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture

and its polyfill:

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/imagecapture-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention that when using the imagecapture-polyfill for taking photos in Safari or Chrome on iOS, I was getting really bad image quality until I added a 2 sec. delay in-between getting the MediaStreamTrack and calling the ImageCapture constructor. This is not really an answer because I don't know why this delay is necessary, but maybe it can help someone anyway.

```
        // Media constraints
        const constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: {
                facingMode: { exact: 'environment' },   // Use the back camera (otherwise the front camera will be used by default)
                width: { ideal: 99999 },
                height: { ideal: 99999 }
            }
        };

        // MediaStream
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(async mediaStream => {    // The user will get a notification on the mobile device that this interface is being used

            // MediaStreamTrack
            const mediaStreamTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

            // ImageCapture
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));    // For an unknown reason, adding this delay greatly increases image quality on iOS
            this.imageCapture = new ImageCapture(mediaStreamTrack);     // Note that iOS doesn't support ImageCapture [as of 2022-11-08] and instead uses the libs/imagecapture-polyfill.js to obtain an image by using the <canvas> instead

            // Take picture
            return this.imageCapture.takePhoto().then(blob => {

                // Upload photo right away
                if (blob) {
```

I also edited the imagecapture-polyfill.js code to get a jpeg instead of a png, greatly reducing the file size.

```
self.canvasElement.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg'); // [YB 2022-11-02: Output jpeg instead of png]
```